# NoMethodError in Links#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

undefined method `created' for #
Extracted source (around line #5):

```
<h2>
  <% link_to link.title, link %><br>
  **<small class="author">Submitted <% time_ago_in_words(link.created+at) %> by <% link.user.email %></small>**
  </h2>
</div>
```

**Update:**

After changing `link.created+at` to `link.created_at`

Its still giving me this error

undefined method `name' for # Extracted source (around line #5):

```
<h2>
  <%= link_to link.title, link %><br>
  <small class="author">Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(link.created_at) %> by <%= link.user.name %></small>
</h2>
```

Comment: This didn't deserve the down-vote.  It is not a poorly written question.  The problem was very obvious to most developers, but we were all new at some point and this question is reasonable.  The error was posted, and sample code was posted.  We had all the information necessary to quickly and easily provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

change `link.created+at` to `link.created_at`

**Update:**

> Its still giving me this error
>
> undefined method `name' for # Extracted source (around line #5):

Your code: `<%= link.user.name %>` is causing an error because there is no method named `name` for `link.user`, try troubleshooting with this information.

Either `link.user` is nil, so it can't call `name` on `user` or there is no method or attribute named `name` on the `user` object (the latter seems most likely).

Comment: When I do that I lose the links that I posted on the website

Comment: Then it means you do not have an attribute (column) or method named `name` in your `User` class.

Answer (score 1):

`run $ bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset` to clear the database.

I'm doing the same tutorial Mackenzie Child Reddit Clone. You're receiving the error because you created a user without a name early in the tutorial. That user needs to removed or add a name to the user to eliminate the error.

Answer (score 0):

I also do the same tutorial and ran into the same problem. I realized there was no name for user in my schema so I ran :

```
rails g migration AddNameToUsers
```

Then I added names to my users in the database.